# Next.js 404 on Dynamic paths when the are many posts

Tags: next.js, next-router

I've built a Next.js app that leverages Tina.io as a headless CMS. I have created a series of posts with dynamic paths. All this is working fine, the posts appear in their respective index and can also be queries with GraphQL.

However, when I add a bunch more posts (still <100), a portion of the posts now 404 when I try to view them. They still appear in the posts index posts however. It seems to be arbitrary - some of the posts that were fine before now 404.

Is there something I should be looking at or refining on how Next or its Router indexes these pages?

Here is my `[filename].js`

```
const ProjectPage = (props) => {
  const { data } = useTina({
    query: props.query,
    variables: props.variables,
    data: props.data,
  });

  return (
    ... content here
  );
};

export default ProjectPage;

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  let data = {};
  let query = {};
  let variables = { relativePath: `${params.filename}.md` };

  try {
    const res = await client.queries.projects(variables);
    query = res.query;
    data = res.data;
    variables = res.variables;
  } catch {
  }

  return {
    props: {
      variables: variables,
      data: data,
      query: query,
    },
  };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const projectsListData = await client.queries.projectsConnection();

  return {
    paths: projectsListData.data.projectsConnection.edges.map((post) => {
      return {
        params: { filename: post.node._sys.filename },
      };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```